# Is this a valid method of solving $3^x + 2^x = 35$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I want to know if this is a valid method of solving this equation:

$3^x + 2^x = 35$

$3^x+2^x = (7)(5)$

$3^x+2^x = (3+2^2)(2+3)$

$3^x+2^x = 3^2 + 2^3 + 18$

$3^x+2^x = 9 + 18 + 2^3 $

$3^x+2^x = 27 + 2^3 $

$3^x+2^x = 3^3 + 2^3 $

And now comes my problem. Is it correct to say that this last equation implies $x=3$? I don't think I can just compare terms just like it was a polynomial...

If this is not correct, is there a way of solving this equation algebraically?

Comment: It *is* correct, but in truth, it is nothing more than speculation as far as I can tell.

Comment: The solution is correct. But can you use the same method to find $x$ for $2^x+3^x=30$?

Comment: I don't see a method here, but there's nothing invalid about it, and in this case it's also correct to conclude from the last equation that $x=3$ is *a* solution. In this case it's pretty obvious that's it's the only solution but in general you have to be careful.

Comment: You could go directly from $3^x + 2^2 = 35$ to $3^x + 2^x = 3^3 +2^3$ without all those steps.

Comment: Or you could go backwards also.

Comment: @Mathlover, no I can't, although I know that there is a unique real solution.

Comment: @Alnitak Just out of curiosity... You knew that $x=3$ was an answer but you felt compelled to write a contrived set of calculations to show that. Why? You could just start your proof with "Notice that $x=3$ is one solution because $3^3+2^3=27+8=35$."... I fear that either you would feel that "it is not math if it does not have calculations" (incorrect: it is perfectly valid!) or that someone may mark this work as incorrect as it does not have calculations (hope they won't teach you for long).

Comment: @user8734617, When I found the problem It was asked how to find the answer $x=3$ without try and error, even though what I did was after knowing the solution is $x=3$ by try and error...

Comment: Ah, but this is a completely different question from what you've asked. For *that*, you would start by noticing that $3^x+2^x$ is strictly increasing, and then you would probably start approximating by halving intervals... $3^0+2^0=1$: too small, $3^4+2^4=97$: too big, $3^2+2^2=13$: too small, $3^3+2^3=35$: just right... This may count as trial and error, but really isn't - it is a very definite algorithm that you're applying, which will solve it for sure in integers, and if there is no integral solution it will give you a real solution with precision of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid method of producing one solution. An additional argument may be called for to show that there are no other solutions. For example, you could argue that $3^x+2^x$ is a one-to-one function.

How do you call the method you used, compared to "algebraically"?

In general, there are no "instant" ways to solve such equations. The fact you were able to solve it in such a nice way is very special. Consider, for example, the equation

> $$3^x+2^x=36.21923341032$$

We know that there *is* a unique solution, (using the mean value theorem, for instance), but there is no way to generate it in closed form, or any other form, except from numerical approximation.

Comment: Thanks. I said algebraically meaning not numerical methods.

Comment: So now I am confused. So why did you ask for an algebraic solution if you already had solved it algebraically?

Comment: I asked for it in case my solution was not correct.

Answer (score 3):

$3$ it's an unique root because $f(x)=3^x+2^x$ is an increasing function and $f(3)=35$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is equivalent to 
$$
f(x)=f(3)\implies x=3
$$
where $f(x)=3^x+2^x$. This is true because $f$ is injective (since it is strictly increasing for example).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, $x=3$ is the only solution in the real numbers.  However, there are infinitely many complex solutions.  For example, there is a solution near $3.40258654642902+5.90727700642090 i$.